# Grep line with specific word from file in a specific column

Tags: ubuntu, awk, grep

I have a file with specific numbers in a column and I want to extract lines which have those numbers in column 3 from another file.

For example, I have `extract.file` with:

```
123
689
456
```

And `input.file` with

```
1 AB 123 home 123
1 AC 568 cat 568
1 BC 689 dog 123
1 BB 456 car 456
```

And I want an outcome file with only:

```
1 AB 123 home 
1 BC 689 dog
1 BB 456 car
```

I used

```
grep -wF -f extract.file input.file > output.file
```

But this includes the last column too:

```
1 BC 689 dog 123
```

So how can I search only in column 3 and exclude the last column from output?

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($3 in a){$NF="";print;}' extract.file input.file
```

To get the whole line without removing the last column:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($3 in a)' extract.file input.file
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it works, is there also a way to use this if I want to delete the lines with the specific numbers in the input file. So to get an output file where the lines with numbers in column 3 are not present any more?

Comment: Sorry, it did not work completely, by using the command I am missing the last column of each line in the output file (the input file has lines with column ranging about the 2000)

Comment: "So how can I search only in column 3 and exclude the last column from output?" Your requirement was to exclude the last column

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant not get the the line who has the word in another column! So only the lines who has the word in the 3th column. Can you help me adjust the script so I get the whole line?

Comment: Updated the solution

Comment: Thank you! And one final question, do you know a way to delete the lines with the specific numbers in column 3 in the input file. So to get an output file where the lines with the extract.file numbers in column 3 are not present any more?

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression in your pattern file:

```
[0-9]\+ [A-Z]\+ 123
[0-9]\+ [A-Z]\+ 689
[0-9]\+ [A-Z]\+ 456


grep -f   extract.file input.file
1 AB 123 home 123
1 BC 689 dog 123
1 BB 456 car 456
```

Comment: Thank you. The files are however not that simple as I made it and around 1.6 GB. I do not have that extra information in the extract.file and can only get it from the input.file. So in order to get that I still need to extract the specific lines...

Comment: why can't you add that preceeding regex constant in `extract.file` using `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score -1):

You could use `cut`:

```
grep -wF -f extract.file input.file | cut -d" "  -f1,2,3,4  >  output.file
```